# Code to remove captions from carousel pictures when browser is on small screen, @media

Tags: html, css

I want the code (HTML, CSS) such as @media to completely remove all the captions on my carousel pictures when the browser window is less than 550px

This CSS code reduces the header for small browsers. I want the same for carousel captions, but to remove captions entirely

```
@media(max-width:550px){
        header{
        font-size:small;
        }
    }
```

Comment: Set the `display` property to `none`. Do you have an example of the html you are using?

Comment: _I want the code_ is not the correct way for asking here. So read [ask], show your html code and your attemps to remove the captions.

Comment: Charlene Vas, thank you. It worked. Sfili, noted. I will ask correctly next time.

Comment: Hi @JohnEdwards Welcome to StackOverflow. If any answer has solved your question please consider accepting it by clicking the check-mark. This indicates to the wider community that you've found a solution and gives some reputation to both the answerer and yourself. There is no obligation to do this.

Answer (score 0):

```
@media(max-width:550px){
           header{
             font-size:small;
           }
           classname{
            display:none;
        }
    }
```

Replace classname with the name of the captions on the  carousel.